# Proof tasks math student need help

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Can we add congruences? If a≡b mod m and c≡d mod m, is it necessarily true that a+c≡b+d mod m? If so, why? If not, provide an example that illustrates why not. To get started on this question, do some numerical examples.

Can we subtract congruences? If a≡b mod m and c≡d mod m, is it necessarily true that a−c≡b−d mod m? If so, why? If not, provide an example that illustrates why not. To get started on this question, do some numerical examples.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, S. Totland! You’ll find that you get a better response here if you give context to your question (where did it come from? Why are you asking about it?) and talk about your thoughts on the problem (what have you tried to solve it? What are the definitions involved?). We try **not** to answer questions that look like homework problems, or that simply state a question and expect a solution.

Comment: You'll notice that your question already has three downvotes and vote to close. That's almost certainly because it appears to be a direct transcription of a homework problem, and the folks who contribute to this site generally don't like doing people's homework. You can show us what you've tried so far by clicking "edit" beneath your question, and you might get more positive results.

Answer (score 3):

Usually we talk about adding congruence classes. For example, if $a=b$ mod(m), we usually say the congruence classes of a and b are equal, that is $[a]=[b]$, and we can add/subtract/multiply two congruence classes.

I'll show the first question and you can do the second one.

By definition, $a=b$ mod(m) $\iff$ $a-b=0$ mod(m) $\iff$ $a-b=tm$ for some $t\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Using this fact, we can see that $$a-b+c-d=tm+sm=(t+s)m$$ for some $t,s\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we add $b+d$ to both sides, we obtain $$a+c=b+d+(t+s)m.$$ Taking mod(m) of both sides, we obtain our result.

Comment: +1 This is correct and well written. That said, I'd rather you waited to answer until the OP showed some effort of his or her own - note the comments on the questions.

Comment: @EthanBolker Noted. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Consider: $$a≡b \mod(m) \hspace{0.5cm} and \hspace{0.5cm} c≡d \mod(m)$$
Then, $$m \mid (a-b) \hspace{0.5cm} and \hspace{0.5cm} m \mid (c-d)$$
So, $$a-b=km \hspace{0.5cm} and \hspace{0.5cm} c-d=k'm$$
Adding, $$(a+c)-(b+d)=(k+k')m$$
Hence, $$ m \mid (a+c)-(b+d)$$

> We get: $$(a+c)≡(b+d) \mod m$$

Similarly, proceed for:  $$(a-c)≡(b-d) \mod m$$

---

You wanted numerical examples:
Take $$7≡5 \mod(2) \hspace{0.5cm} and \hspace{0.5cm} 10≡4 \mod(2)$$
$$7+10≡5+4 \mod(2)$$ or $$10≡4 \mod(2)$$ $$17≡9 \mod(2)$$
Similarly,
 $$7-10≡5-4 \mod(2)$$ or $$-3≡1 \mod(2)$$